# Microeconomics. How to solve mathematically Exchange/Edgeworth Box models.

Tags: calculus, economics

[Problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3I0S6.png)

Hey guys. First post here. So im an econ student and these are the questions i am faced with VS the answers that i am supposed to have. I understand Edgeworth Box models from the lecture notes they provided but there were no examples mathematically. it was just 100 drawings so im stumped when it comes to whats happening here. I'm assuming it has to do with the MRS of the goods but i really dont know where to start.

Any tips on how to solve these problems?

thank you

Comment: Don't know how it works in economics ;-) but in mathematics, starting with *precise* definitions is nearly always a good idea.

Comment: The only suggestion I can make is to look at Mas-Colell's explanation of Edgeworth Boxes in ch. 15.B.  Mas-Colell's book is mathematically clear.  You don't give us any specific question to try to answer.

Comment: This may be better asked in http://economics.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: The questions are linked under the word "problems" as well as the desired answers. I have no idea how to get to those answers

Comment: @YusufEdros Not too sure what you mean... could you explain what your problem is further? Also note that you need to use the @ to alert people that you have responded. I didn't see this without manually checking.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, in economics it is common practice to explain everything with pictures, without a single non-trivial formula.
Leaving no hope for any computational approach.

On the other hand, if a concrete algebraic or differential equations were used for the models, the complexity of all the derivations and proofs would be tremendous.

That's sort of justifies the explanations in terms of inequalities only.